# $\liminf$ for random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, random-variables

If I have a sequence of real numbers such that $\liminf_{k\to\infty} a_k=0$, then it is *equivalent* to having a subsequence $a_{n_k}$ such that this subsequence converges to $0$.

Now, suppose that I have a random variable such that $\liminf_k X_k =0$ almost surely. Is that equivalent to the fact that there is a subsequence of $X_k$  that converges to $0$ almost surely?

(The motivation for this is that in my research, I have a sequence of RVs that converges to $0$ in probability, so I know that a subsequence converges to $0$ almost surely. I was wondering if this is equivalent to the $\liminf$ result)

Comment: It's equivalent to having such a subsequence AND having no subsequence converging to any negative number.  You could say your condition is equivalent to $\liminf\limits_{k\to\infty} a_k \le 0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: "I know that a subsequence converges to 0 almost surely" --- This phrasing could be understood as meaning there is some particular subsequence that almost surely converges to $0$, but I think you must have meant almost surely there is _some_ subsequence (not the same set of indices for every realization of the random variables) that converges to $0$. So a better phrasing might be in order. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, oops. I forgot to mention that the RV is non-negative. Also, about your second comment. I see what you're saing.  Quoting the result I'm referring to " Convergence in probability implies existence of a subsequence that converges almost surely to the same limit."

Comment: @MichaelHardy Do you know of any proof/resource to get started? I know I have to somehow use Borel-Cantelli to show this but I'm not a stochastics guy

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $X_1,X_2,X_3,\ldots\sim\text{i.i.d. }\mathrm{Bernoulli}(1/2)$.  Then
$$
\Pr\left(\liminf_{n\to\infty} X_n =0 \right) = 1
$$
but there is no particular set $A$ of indices $n$ such that
$$
\Pr\left( \liminf_{\begin{smallmatrix} n\to\infty \\ n\in A \end{smallmatrix}} X_n=0 \right) = 1.
$$

Comment: You're right. I guess what I was looking for is the equivalence between "knowing that there exists a subsequence that converges almost surely to 0" and "liminf of that sequence being 0"